# App Store Search Result displays a generic app icon - though listing is ok

Tags: ios, icons, app-store, app-store-connect

My App Icon is an important element for attracting users from the search results onto the listing itself.

Upon a search on the App Store, the search results shows my app listed with a generic app icon.
When I go into the app listing - my app icon is displayed fine.
Where is this icon taken from? Where do I set it?

I have - I believe - submitted [all required icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html) in my bundle.

I have also followed and complied with the [Apple requirements for the 'Large App Icon'] in iTunes Connect.
"The large app icon is displayed for your app on the App Store and, if needed, is used to feature your app on the App Store.
iOS app icons need to meet the following requirements..."

Here's a screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/doxc4s6vdjkudhe/Photo%202-05-2014%208%2016%2013%20am.png

Comment: That is not a generic icon.

Comment: I've edited the question with a new link to the screenshot

Comment: It's the same screenshot and the app icon is still not generic.

Comment: I don't know what icon it is. I get the same icon when I do the same search in the App Store app. Perhaps you should write to Apple about this.

Comment: It is the icon in the top left of the .png. It is blue with a white sillouette of a head and shoulders. I believe this to be an apple supplied icon. I have no idea how to change it. I have left a question on the Apple developer forums.
https://devforums.apple.com/thread/225397?tstart=0

Comment: The icon has text in it. Specifically FB iOS - SDK. It looks like you took a generic project or sample from facebook and that icon was kept in your project.

Answer (score 0):

lnjuanj, your comment has answered the question. If you post as an answer I will accept it.

It turns out the file is either Icon-72@2x.png or Icon-72.png and was a Facebook SDK icon. 
Somehow these the Facebook SDK icons were copied into my supporting files folder.

Comment: That was also _my_ answer. I kept telling you it wasn't generic. By that, I meant that this icon was in your project - it was your icon, somehow.

Comment: True - and thank you. It was Injuanj who provided a little extra context that finally got my brain to make the connection. Happy for you to leave an answer and for me to vote it up - if I'm allowed given my newbie status on SO.